# boto3 s3 copy_object with ContentEncoding argument

Tags: amazon-s3, copy, boto3, content-encoding

I'm trying to copy s3 object with boto3 command like below

```
import boto3 
client = boto3.client('s3')
client.copy_object(Bucket=bucket_name, ContentEncoding='gzip', CopySource=copy_source, Key=new_key)
```

To copy the object succeeded, but **ContentEncoding** metadata was not added to the object.

When I use the console to add Content-Encoding metadata, there was no problem.

But using python boto3 copy command, it cannot do that.

Here's a document link about **client.copy_object()**

https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.copy_object

And the application versions are like this.

> python=2.7.16
>
> boto3=1.0.28
>
> botocore=1.13.50

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Just checking... Was the original object in gzip format? Did it have the `ContentEncoding` metadata set?

Comment: original object is gzip from another etl data but, has not "Content-Encoding=gzip" tag.

Answer (score 3):

Try adding  MetadataDirective='REPLACE' to your copy_object call

```
client.copy_object(Bucket=bucket_name, ContentEncoding='gzip', CopySource=copy_source, Key=new_key, MetadataDirective='REPLACE')
```